# joomla get post data

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm creating joomla component and i have problem with accesing data from post

in one view i have 6 inboxes 3 of them are chandled by JTable class and thats good, but other 3 i want to process, my fields:

```
<input id="jform[team1_goals_players]" class="" type="hidden" name="jform[team1_goals_players]" value="2,2," aria-invalid="false">
<input id="jform_team1_goals" class="required" type="text" value="4" name="jform[team1_goals]" aria-required="true" required="required" aria-invalid="false">
```

first one is field that i want to process and second is chandled by JTable class by using

```
$sth = JRequest::get('team1_goals_players');
```

$sth is empty

where i should use JRequest to get that value and other 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sth` is empty because there is no variable like  `team1_goals_players` in the form.You must try like this- first get `jform` and then read  `team1_goals_players` from jform.

```
$post = JRequest::get('jform');
$sth = $post['team1_goals_players'];
```

More about [JRequest](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_data_from_GET_and_POST_requests).

Comment: For Joomla 2.5 JRequest was deprecated. You should be using JInput instead (see here http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput )

Answer (score 8):

JRequest is deprecated in 2.5.

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$post = $jinput->get('jform', array(), 'array');
$sth = $post['team1_goals_players'];
```

Comment: This should be: $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;