# PHP doesn't insert in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla, module

I'm working on a Joomla module. I'm trying to take input from a form and insert it into a database. Here's my "helper.php" code:

```
<?php

/** post form to db module **/

// No direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );



//--build the form------------>
?>
<form name="names" id="names" action="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" method="post">
  <p><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" /></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="" /></p>
  <p><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Names" /></p>
</form>
<!-- //--END BUILD THE FORM--------| -->
<?
if( (isset($_POST['lname'])) || (isset($_POST['fname'])) ) {
   //first name or last name set, continue-->
   $lname = $_POST['lname'];
   $fname = $_POST['fname'];
/*   $data =new stdClass();
   $data->id = NULL;
   $data->firstname = $fname;
   $data->lastname = $lname;*/

   $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
   $query = "INSERT INTO `#__names` (`fname`, `lname`)
      VALUES ($fname, $lname);";
   $db->setQuery( $query );
   $db->query(); 

}  else {
  echo '<h4>One Field Is Required!</h4>';
}

?>
```

I can see the form, but when I submit the data it doesn't update the database table. I've checked the Apache error log but it doesn't contain any information about it. What am I missing?

Comment: `$db =& JFactory::getDBO();` is a bit PHP4, just drop the ampersand...  then learn about injection, then learn to write decent queries, then use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. I know this is blunt, but your code hurts

Comment: What version of joomla are you on?

Comment: My Joomla! version is Joomla! 2.5.

Comment: Then first you should be using JForm if at all possible and not useing _POST and  second you should be using jdatabasequery to properly build your query with correct quoting also you are not building this query 2.5 style you need to put $db = JFactory::getDbo();
 
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

Comment: As for the database query, I would follow Elin's answer below. You should also not be using `$_POST` and should be using this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13213833/1362108

Answer (score 3):

For your query it should be more like this, the way you have it will not work in 2.5.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true)

->insert($db->quoteName('#__names'))
->columns(array($db->quoteName('fname', 'lname')))
->values($db->quote($fname),$db->quote($lname));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. This is what the Apache error log says: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in...[skipped]`

Comment: ack take off that semicolon. ... fixed

Comment: I got the same output. No visualization and same message in Apache error log.

Comment: Check to make sure you don't have a semi colon before the -> in whatever line you are getting the error on. Or don't use chaining.

Comment: I just copied what's currently in your answer. The error is in the last line `->values($db->quote($fname),$db->quote($lname));`

Comment: Missing ) on the preceding line.

Comment: The visualization error is fixed now, but still no success inserting the data in the database.

Comment: Dump out the generated query and test it in phpmyadmin ... $query->dump();

Answer (score 1):

Remove `;` from query and add quotes to the strings `$fname` and `$lname`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `#__names` (`fname`, `lname`)
          VALUES ('".$fname."', '".$lname."')";
```

And **OPTIONALLY** you need to insert `NULL` if the fields are empty like

```
$lname = (trim($lname) != '') ? $lname : 'NULL';
$fname = (trim(fname) != '') ? $fname : 'NULL';
```

Comment: Print the `$_POST` before the insert query and tell me

Comment: `print($_POST);` outputs `Array`. If I print `$_POST['fname']` or `$_POST['lname']` I get what I put on the field.

Comment: We can print with print_r($_POST); to display all the array values,And another once check your DB is connected or not..

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` outputs `Array ( [fname] => s [lname] => s [submit] => Submit Names [view] => article [option] => com_content )`, being "s" the value I introduced. I also checked the db connection with `mysql_ping()` which returned true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `#__names` (`fname`, `lname`)
  VALUES ('$fname', '$lname');";
```

Comment: Don't use insert into if you will ever use a database taht isn't mysql.

Comment: @Elin: ?? What do you mean? [MSSql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977880(v=vs.71).aspx), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-insert.html), SQLite... all know `INSERT INTO`... Besides, if you're likely to change DB adapters, you want an ORM, with a decent API that doesn't require hard-coded queries

Comment: yeah that was goofy, there are differences on inserting but not this case, BUT he should be using the joomla query builder, not using strings like this.

Comment: @Elin: Oh, I see what you mean... well, differences in `INSERT INTO` _do_ apply: PostgreSQL follows the standards in a psychotic way, so it doesn't do backticks, hence the query would fail anyway. I agree with you on the query builder (that's why I said you need an ORM)